# Given $P(A \cap B^c)$, $P(B \cap A^c),$ and $P(A \cup B)$, find $P(A)$

Tags: probability, logic

Given $P(A \cap B^c)=0.6$ and $P(B \cap A^c)=0.2$ and $P(A \cup B)=0.8$, is there a way to find $P(A)$?

Comment: Draw a venn diagram.

Comment: De Morgan's Law may help too.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen I did try that. But what I get is a diagram with an unshaded $intersection$, so does that mean there is no intersection and A and B are mutually exclusive and A and B are not independent?

Answer (score 0):

$A\cup B= A\cup (B\cap A^\complement)$ where $A$ and $B\cap A^\complement$ are disjoint.

So $\mathsf P(A\cup B)=\mathsf P(A~\cup~(B\cap A^\complement))$

Now the probability for a union of disjoint events is equal to...

Comment: Is it equal to the sum of the disjoint events? so $A U B = P((A\cap B^\complement)\cup~(B\cap A^\complement))$ $= P(only A) + P(only B).$ Thus $P(A\cap B)= 0$?

Comment: Concluding, $P(A) = P(A\cap B^\complement) = P(only A)= 0.6$ ?